# Handle setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener in Kotlin adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener in adapter to pass the click to the activity. I've searched a lot of and I only found some examples of how to do one clicklistener but not handle both at the same time.

How can I handle both listeners in the activity?

ADAPTER

```
class BrowserAdapter(private val voucherList: List<String>?, private val listener: (String) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BrowserAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(inflate(parent.context, R.layout.item_web, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(voucherList!![position], listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return voucherList!!.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(urlData: String, listener: (String) -> Unit) = with(itemView) {
            tx_url.text = urlData

            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener(urlData)
            }

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener{
                listener(urlData)
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY

```
 rv_web_items.adapter = BrowserAdapter(Preferences.getFavouritesWebsites()) {
            presenter.onItemClick(it)
        }
```

Comment: Just pass a `boolean` for both long click & onClick

Comment: I've tried to pass a boolean like this (listener(urlData, true)) in MyViewHolder, but the code is crashing in Activity (presenter.onItemClick(it)) unresolved reference 'it'. Could you type some code to how to do it, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda function of the activity should look like :-

```
val listener : (String, Boolean) -> Unit = { urlData, isLongClick -> presenter.onItemClick(urlData) }
```

Then pass the lambda ( `listener` ) to the adapter

```
rv_web_items.adapter = BrowserAdapter(Preferences.getFavouritesWebsites(), listener)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to add listeners at `onBindViewHolder` like this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        }
```

and also long click:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener { true  }
```

and what about sending data to activity. First step - create interface:

```
interface Click {
    fun sendData(..., position: Int, ...) // it is only example
}
```

the the second step use it at your adapter:

```
open class Adapter(..., ..., private val click: Click)
```

then handle click and send data:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            click.sendData(your_data)
        }
```

then in activity you have to declare this interface:

```
 val adapter = Adapter(..., ..., this@YourActivity)
```

function for getting data in your activity:

```
override fun sendData(your_data) {
    }
```

and also don't forget to implement this interface:

```
class JobsList : ..., ..., Click
```

I hope it will help you. Good Luck :)